# Angular2 custom validator not called

Tags: forms, validation, typescript, angular, custom-validators

I have written a custom validation directive like that:

```
const DURATION_VALIDATOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALIDATORS,
    {useExisting: forwardRef(() => DurationDirective), multi: true}
);


@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][duration], [formControl][duration]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => DurationDirective),
        multi: true }]
})
export class DurationDirective  implements Validator{
    constructor(public model:NgModel){
        console.error('init')
    }
    validate(c:FormControl) {
        console.error('validate')
        return {'err...':'err...'};
    }
}
```

My Html looks like this:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="preparation.duration"
    duration 
    required
>
```

My problem is that while the validator is initialized, i.e. 'init' is logged to console, the validate function is never called, i.e. 'validate' is never logged to the console, when typing into the input field. Since the validator is initialized, I assume that I "wired" up everything correctly. So what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best bet is that you haven't bootstraped Angular with regards to forms:

```
import { App } from './app';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(App, [
    // these are crucial
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
  ]);
```

You can see this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/JOOZfqCjr1UD8nL6U9r2?p=preview) - it does output `"validate"` to the console.

Comment: I have added the disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms() to my component providers property. But this does not seem to have any effect. Can you explain why? Here is my updated plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/ztuBIZc3QMRwMg62scZR?p=preview

Comment: That plunk still doesn't have the two provide calls in the bootstrap() call. Moving the two calls you have in your providers property to the bootstrap method fixes the issue. https://plnkr.co/edit/b2PipR?p=preview

Comment: Sorry that was a misunderstanding. I intentionally moved the the provide calls from the bootstrap method to the my-app component to illustrate my question: my assumption was that adding the 2 provide calls to the component providers, is sufficient. Can you explain why not?

Comment: I have created a separate question for this special problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687705/angular2-providers-in-bootstrap-vs-component

Comment: @batesiiic, how did you get your plunk to work?  When I tried what you have, the Broccoli compiler complains that FormControl and Validator are not defined, as they were never imported.  Is this because I have loaded "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4" whereas your plunk loads 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular' directly from the CDN? which is a different release?  I can't even load that URL directly.

Comment: @LawrenceI.Siden, I'm having trouble finding a good CDN for rc4, but the new forms stuff is inside of `@angular/forms`, something like `import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";` We're using RC4 and it's all working for us (after some pain we had to work through of course)

Comment: @batesiic, I just fixed my problem before you posted.  Although I provided disableDeprecateForms() and provideForms() in bootstrap, I was still importing form-related classes from @angular/common.  So rc4 isn't to blame.

Regardless, could you tell me how that plunker can work without explicitly importing Validators and FormControl?  Also, Typescript would not compile my code unless I used AbstractControl in the signature to my Validator.validator() function.  I'm just trying to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

I forked and improved @batesiiic 's plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/Vokcid?p=preview

```
validate(c:FormControl) {
    console.error('called validate()')
    return parseInt(c.value) < 10 ? null : {
      duration: {message: 'Please enter a number < 10'}
    };
}
```

The validate() method must return null if the input is valid, otherwise, it returns an object { key: value, ... } where key is the type of error and value can be anything you can use in your template to generate an error message.

The template also contains a div to display the error message if the input is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the custom validator function as class/component/Directive method,
Writing Custom validator outside the component/Directive should work.

```
validate(c:FormControl) {
    console.error('validate')
    return {'err...':'err...'};
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][duration], [formControl][duration]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => DurationDirective),
        multi: true }]
})
export class DurationDirective  implements Validator{
    constructor(public model:NgModel){
        console.error('init')
    }

}
```