# Angular2 providers in bootstrap vs @component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, provider

From my understanding, you can define your application providers in your bootstrap call like this:

```
bootstrap(
  App,
  [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()]]
)
```

or in your root component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()],
  ...
)
```

However, I have created a form validator plugin that required the provideForms providers and this directive only works, when the bootstrap options. I have created a [plunk to illstrate the problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/ztuBIZc3QMRwMg62scZR?p=preview): the validator works, if I add the providerForms() to the bootstrap call. As soon as I comment out the providerForms() from the bootstrap call, the validator does not work anymore. I assumed that the providerForms definition in the component was sufficient. Any explaination?

Comment: Runtime compiler is created before you're injecting providers into AppComponent. This way compiler uses old forms classes into AppComponent.template.js. Method `useFactory` within providers of AppComponent is firing only when you insert token into the constructor. https://plnkr.co/edit/Ed8ao38phPNsYeHMorcg?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular2 DI always looks upwards for providers of a requested dependency. If a service that is instantiated by bootstrap requires a dependency than it doesn't get one injected that is provided further down the tree.

Providing at `bootstrap(...)` and `@Component(...)` of the root component are not equivalent but this distinction is not relevant for everything inside the root component or one of its children or other descendants.
`bootstrap()` is one level higher than the root component.

The Angular2 style-guide also suggests to prefer the root component over `bootstrap()` because bootstrap should be reserved for system stuff.

Forms and the router need to be instantiated before the first component is created (there was for example a bug in early versions of the V3 router where the root component needed to inject `Router` or contain a `routerLink`, otherwise the router wouldn't start up).

So because some things need to be instantiated before the root component gets created the situation comes up where the difference between `bootstrap()` and root component becomes relevant.

Comment: Do you have an idea which part of these providers is responsible for this behaviour? What should we look for when figuring out if the provider is eligible for non-root injector or not? I was hoping that we've left config/run discrimination in A1, but it looks all the same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "which part". I only know from mentions in Angular2 GitHub issues that `provideRouter()` needs to be used in `bootstrap()` instead of root components. I'm not surprised that `disableDeprecatedForms()` and `provideForms()` require the same, but I don't know details about why exactly.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the mentioned github issues?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It would be nice to know what are the exact conditions that can force the provider to be used in `bootstrap` only. I guess it is APP_INITIALIZER in the case of router. Not sure what about forms... maybe CompilerConfig ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason this is important to you? It doesn't bother me too much because I expect bigger changes in this area anyway with the introduction of modules in the next release.